# 403 Error with WiFi Hotspots

Tags: ios, wifi, nsurlconnection, afnetworking, http-status-code-403

I have an iOS app that connects to a Django server via XMLRPC (the protocol doesn't really matter).  Authentication is persisted with standard cookies and is transparently handled by `AFNetworking` via `NSURLConnection`.  The Django XMLRPC library returns a `403` error when a request fails authentication, and when this happens the app displays a login page to the user.  This approach has worked fine for a few years.

A recent problem came up with a user who connected to a WiFi hotspot but did not authenticate with the hotspot.  They loaded the app and was shown the login page, which must have been the result of a `403` error coming back from the hotspot.  If they first authenticate with the hotspot then everything works fine.

I'm trying to find a solution to prevent my app from interpreting such `403` errors as a failed authentication.  I assume one of two things are happening:

- the hotspot redirects to a URL that returns a `403` error; or
- the hotspot immediately returns a `403` error.

The first scenario is easy to manage by blocking `301` and `302` redirects.  Fortunately, `AFNetworking` makes this easy.

The second scenario is more difficult and I see no way of knowing from where the `403` originated.

Does anyone know if there is anything else in the header to detect the origin of a `403`, or if there is a standard practice of redirecting the request when not signed into a hotspot?

**Edit**

Here are what my Django service header looks like on a `403`:

```
HTTP/1.1 403 FORBIDDEN
Server: nginx
Date: Sun, 28 Apr 2013 07:21:34 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Cookie
Set-Cookie: sessionid=5a5ce154d1229e40c3773e8f6999a32d; expires=Sun, 18-Aug-2013 07:21:34 GMT; httponly; Max-Age=9676800; Path=/
```

Comment: You can log the returned headers to see what's available. Do you have access to modify the web service?

Comment: I regret the hotspot in question is on the other side of the world, so I can't check that.  I edited my question to show what the headers from my webservice looks like... Nothing useful there.

Comment: Now that I think about it... I could create some middleware to add something to the `HTTPRepsonse` to identify the source of the response...  Seems like a hack.

Comment: Not an answer, but wondering why the server is sending a 403 (Forbidden) if there is an authentication required. IMO, it should be a 401 (Unauthorized). A 403 would normally mean, the server will refuse to respond in any case and the client should give up asking those requests.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Valid question!  It's in the implementation of the XMLRPC library I'm using.  It's programmed to return HttpResponseForbidden() if anything goes wrong.  Probably not correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution I could find was to add a custom header to the responses from my Django server, and validate the header in the client to assure it came from the server and not the hotspot.